# replace dataframe values from another list with specific indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe which has a column date and I'm trying to replace with another list based on index, for example:
wrong_dates_indexes has list of indexes where date is in wrong format in original dataframe df:

```
dirty_dates_indexes=[4,33,48,54,59,91,95,132,160,175,180,197,203,206,229,237,266,271,278,294,298,333,348,373,380,420,442]

formated_dates=['2019-04-25','2019-12-01','2019-06-16','2019-10-07','2019-08-06','2019-02-17','2019-11-20','2019-03-10','2019-10-11','2019-03-04','2019-07-31','2019-10-12','2019-09-13','2019-08-26','2019-12-29','2019-10-11','2019-11-20','2019-06-16','2019-12-12','2019-03-22','2019-01-21','2019-03-21','2019-10-15','2019-12-01','2019-03-20','2019-09-08','2019-08-19']
```

I'm trying to replace all values in df with indexed in
wrong_dates_indexes with values in formated_dates.

I've tried the following code, however receiving an error:

```
for index in dirty_dates_indexes:
    df.loc[index].date.replace(df.loc[index].date,formated_dates(f for f in range(0,len(range(formated_dates)))))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How to solve this? or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the value from `dirty_dates_indexes` and use that to lookup the position in `formatted_dates`. It may be messing you up.

You are using loc instead of iloc to reach the specific row.

Here's what I did.

```
dirty_dates_indexes=[4,33,48,54,
                     59,91,95,132,
                     160,175,180,197,
                     203,206,229,237,
                     266,271,278,294,
                     298,333,348,373,
                     380,420,442]
formated_dates=['2019-04-25','2019-12-01','2019-06-16','2019-10-07',
                '2019-08-06','2019-02-17','2019-11-20','2019-03-10',
                '2019-10-11','2019-03-04','2019-07-31','2019-10-12',
                '2019-09-13','2019-08-26','2019-12-29','2019-10-11',
                '2019-11-20','2019-06-16','2019-12-12','2019-03-22',
                '2019-01-21','2019-03-21','2019-10-15','2019-12-01',
                '2019-03-20','2019-09-08','2019-08-19']

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['dirty_dates'] = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=500,freq='D')

for i,row_id in enumerate(dirty_dates_indexes):
    df.dirty_dates.iloc[row_id] = pd.to_datetime(formated_dates[i])


print (df.head(20))
```

The results are as follows:

```
   dirty_dates
0   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02
2   2019-01-03
3   2019-01-04
4   2019-04-25  # <-- this row changed
5   2019-01-06
6   2019-01-07
7   2019-01-08
8   2019-01-09
9   2019-01-10
10  2019-01-11
11  2019-01-12
12  2019-01-13
13  2019-01-14
14  2019-01-15
15  2019-01-16
16  2019-01-17
17  2019-01-18
18  2019-01-19
19  2019-01-20
```